# Form vs just a div with inputs and a button with event listener

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to know if for security or other reasons it's best to use form element or just a div with some inputs and a button with an event listener inside it.

For example for getting user credentials is it a security concern to not use the form element? and then just send the input values with javascript?

Comment: Why would you want to use div?

Comment: It makes sense due to accessibility and usability.

Comment: Forms have many useful features and behaviours that users expect. Programming the same features and behaviours from plain elements is difficult, creates an inconsistent UI and is just a waste of code.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i also found this question very Interesting when i thought little for about this question .

Then i search on google and ask to my senior about this question .

**Why Form tag needed ?**

Here the my answer :

**Description**

The HTML `<form>` tag is used for creating a form for user input. A form can contain `textfields`, `checkboxes`, `radio-buttons` and more. Forms are used to pass user-data to a specified URL.

This tag supports all the global attributes described in HTML Attribute Reference

**Specific Attributes**

[image]

**Event Attributes**

[image]

For More read this [Link](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/2435-are-html-form-tags-required-to-display-form-input-controls.htm)